# Do I have to call 'longjmp' after a 'setjmp'

Tags: c, setjmp

In the manpage on `longjmp` and `setjmp`, there's this line:

> If the function which called `setjmp()` returns before `longjmp()` is
>   called, the behaviour is undefined.

Does that mean that I actually must call `longjmp` somewhere in the function that called `setjmp` or in a nested function? Or is it OK to not call it at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're reading wrong.

> If the function which called setjmp() returns before longjmp() is called, the behaviour is undefined.

The behaviour of `longjmp` is undefined if you call it *after* you returned from the function which set the `setjmp`. But it's perfectly all right *not* to call `longjmp` at all.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h) is clearer:

> If the function in which setjmp was called returns, it is no longer possible to safely use longjmp with the corresponding jmp_buf object.
>
> This is because the stack frame is invalidated when the function returns. Calling longjmp restores the stack pointer, which—because the function returned—would point to a non-existent and potentially overwritten or corrupted stack frame.

Those functions are often used to handle exception mechanisms. If the exception doesn't occur, you don't want to call `longjmp` because there's no reason to "rewind" your program.